# Incorrect xml Content

Tags: android, android-studio

Android studio 3.5 parsing the XML layout file incorrectly (See screenshot).

I've tried reinstalling the android studio but didn't helped.
[image]

Screenshot of XML code in android studio

[image]

Fortunately, My XML code is fine (I also have a backup), so its problem with android studio. Does anyone have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: it is impossible this to be valid xml, you have several unclosed tags and your list element is missing `>`

Comment: Which language you are using to create the view?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid xml file for android studio. This kind of xml file android studio does not supports.
So please make sure what you have to make with this xml.
Thanks